# Migrating android application project using AndroidAnnotations from Android Studio 0.8 to 1.0 version

Tags: android, android-studio, migration, android-annotations

I’m trying to migrate an android application project from Android Studio 0.8 to 1.0 version. The project uses [AndroidAnnotations](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations) framework.

The problem arises when you try to supply the custom arguments required by AndroidAnnotations with the APT Plugin.

Using this instruction will lead to the next compiler error: *Could not find property 'processResources'*

```
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName “com.rf.commons”
    }
}
```

Any thoughts will be appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: You should always check the wiki, the solution you found out is there in the Getting started page.

Comment: What wiki? Could you post the link, please?

Comment: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle. This is the link, I suppose. Thanks.

Comment: That's it! Sorry i could not paste it because i was on mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing Gradle file as follow should solve the problem:

```
apt {
    arguments {
       androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
       resourcePackageName "your.package.name"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should accept your own answer, it saved me a lot of time, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll do it, but I can't accept my own answer until 2 days xD New rules.

Answer (score 3):

valbertos answer works perfectly. Just to add a few details - processResources has been deprecated. See the link below:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

**version 0.14.3 (2014/11/18)**
Variant.packageApplication/zipAlign/createZipAlignTask/outputFile/processResources/processManifest (use the variant output)

So as valbertos mentioned, following changes works well:

```
apt {
    arguments {
       androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
       resourcePackageName <your package name>
    }
}
```

**EDIT : (From the comments from valbertos: It is just to put everything at one place)**

AndroidAnnotation wiki explains the steps needs to be done in order to make it work.

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle